# python exception, windows error: [error 2] the system cannot find the file specified: "blabla.pyc"

Tags: python

I have a problem here

I'm trying to create a program that can remove pyc files. The problem is every time I run the program through cmd, always appears a message like this:

> windows error: [error 2] the system cannot find the file specified: "blabla.pyc"

And, this is the code:

```
directory = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\baba\\My Documents"

    try:
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
            for file in fnmatch.filter(files, p):

                print "mencari... ",root

                size = os.path.getsize(file)
                dateTime = time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(file))                   
                dateTuple = time.localtime(os.path.getmtime(file))
                dateFile = dateTuple[0:3]                                           
                todayTuple = time.localtime(time.time())
                todayFile = todayTuple[0:3]

                if size == 0:
                    print "\n\n\t File name %s size %d bytes \n" %(file, size)
                    choice()
```

I know, here so many have asked this. But, every time I tried, no one has managed one.

Oh, every time I put a comment from size variable to bottom, the program can run smoothly. But, when I do not comment, the issue resurfaced.

There must be something wrong with my logic. Can anyone make a suggestion? I really do not know what to do anymore.

thank you for your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More or less guessing:

Try replacing `file` with `os.path.join(root, file)`:

```
absfile = os.path.join(root, file)

size = os.path.getsize(absfile)
dateTime = time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(absfile))                   
dateTuple = time.localtime(os.path.getmtime(absfile))
```

`files` as returned by `os.walk` returns a list of filenames - not full paths:
E.g. `"blabla.pyc"`, while you would need `"C:\\Documents and Settings\\baba\\My Documents\blabla.pyc"`

So if you're not running this script from the `directory`, `getmtime` etc will fail.